# Does electric potential influence the direction of current?

Tags: voltage, current, basic, energy

**Main goal**

My main goal right now is trying to understand what negative voltage means, since I know AC can have a negative voltage and so can any electric component. I've pretty much read and seen most articles/posts forums/video's on negative voltages, but it's still confusing me. I hope understanding the following will help me grasp this concept.

**My confusion**

I read in some articles that "the direction of current is dependent on the electric potential, because charge flows from high potential to low potential". I, however, always thought that the potential had nothing to do with this, because the direction of current depends on the rule "opposite charges attract, like charges repel". So in convential current, the charges move from the positive to the negative terminal. I just viewed potential as a property, i.e. the amount of joules that charges are carrying (joules/coulomb).

Please correct me where I'm wrong. If it's true that current flows from high potential to low potential, negative voltage would make sense to me, because it means the side of the positive terminal always has a higher potential. Assume point A is at the start of the circuit, and point B at the end of the circuit. So when the positive and negative terminals switch (which happens in AC), point A will have a negative potential, and point B will have a high potential (instead of the opposite), which means the voltage is negative.

**Just to be clear,** I want an answer to these two questions: Does electric potential influence the direction of current? And is the little story I wrote correct?

Comment: *"opposite charges attract, like charges repel"*

Comment: @nidhin oops!! lol. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does electric potential influence the direction of current?

Yes it does. As you said, conventional current flow is from a higher potential to a lower one.

With your typical AC waveform (a sinusoid), the voltages don't switch discretely. They gradually increase or decrease. For one half of a cycle, one terminal will be higher than the other, and you will have current flow from the more positive to the more negative. For the next half of the cycle, the other terminal will be higher, and you will have current flow again from whichever terminal has a higher potential relative to the other. This is conventional current flow.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I understand now. But you say one terminal will be higher than the other, but I've been told with AC, the terminals just switch places. Which one is correct?

Comment: Which leads me to the following question: Does the positive terminal always have a higher electric potential?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are reading or who has been telling you stuff, but I'd double check your sources because there is some confusion happening. A terminal is a physical entry or exit node for a signal to enter or exit. But its something physical.

Comment: Read what I said in the answer. One terminal will be higher than the other for half a cycle, and then be lower for the other half. I don't understand what you are asking with "does the positive terminal always have a higher electric potential?"

Comment: So basically, the potential energy is just changing constantly on both terminals? Excuse my lack of knowledge... I'm trying to learn

Comment: That's right. .

Comment: Have a read over this page - http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-waveform.html

Comment: "Voltage" is the "push" that causes electrons to start moving "through" conductors. (For the most part, electrons travel along the outside of conductors, not inside them.) Okay so then without any voltage difference, there can't be any current flow. If there was +1v, 0v (ground), and -1v, connecting something (lets say a 1 Ohm resistor) between +1 and GND, would allow 1 Ampere of current to flow to GND. Likewise, connecting the resistor between GND and -1v would also allow 1A to flow, towards -1v. But connecting it from +1 to -1 is no longer 1 volt - it's 2 volts. So 2A would flow. (DC.)

Comment: @efox29 the article says the terminals change as well, quote: "An AC waveform is constantly changing its polarity every half cycle alternating between a positive maximum value and a negative maximum value"

Comment: Yup. Which is what I said. Look at the sine wave on the link I sent. You can think of the x axis is one terminal, and the blue wave is another terminal. Notice how the x axis does not move, but its the blue one that does. So each half cycle, the blue wave alternates polarity

Comment: @efox29 I get the concept behind the electric potential alternating. I think I'm confused on what polarity means. What is your definition of polarity?

Comment: You can think of polarity in electronics as positive and negative. Signals that are only positive or only negative are unipoloar (having only one sign - positive or negative but not both) and signals that go both positive and negative are bipolar (two signs - positive and negative). So alternating polarity means it alternates between positive and negative.

Comment: @efox29 Can you correct me where I'm wrong: With AC we say a terminal (which is physical) switches between positive and negative signs? So the positive terminal becomes negative for a period of time, but it's still the same terminal?

Comment: thats right. The negative terminal would be used a reference in which to compare the positive terminal.

Comment: @efox29 Thank you so much for your time! Last question: Say we're using the following circuit http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/02018.png , and we're at a certain moment in time where the top terminal is positive, and the bottom terminal is negative. The voltage should be positive at this moment in time, right? At this same moment in time, the electrons are at the negative terminal, so the potential is higher at the negative terminal. Doesn't this mean the voltage is negative then? Or is this because of conventional current?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23228/discussion-between-efox29-and-user1534664).